# how to apply zoom in /zoom out animation action on a button in android cocos2dx

Tags: android, sprite

i am developing an android game and on the main menu i want to apply an animation on the play button that it automatically zoom in and zoom out repeatedly. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

do something like this.

```
Action *zoomIN = ScaleBy::create(0.5f, 0.7f);
Action *zoomOut = zoomIN->reverse();
RepeatForever *zoomSeq = Sequence::create(zoomIN, zoomOut, NULL);
playButton->runAction(zoomSeq);
```

change values inside scaleBy according to your need, Also you can try ScaleTo to get other effects. Please refer this [Link](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.2/db/d61/classcocos2d_1_1_action.html) for more Actions related Information

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have done it but it gives the effect like sprite is moving a little point

Comment: didn't understand  by what u mean a little point.  be specific,  is sprite changing its position?  if yes then u also need to set anchor point according to scale ratio, try playbutton->anchorPoint(0.5,0.5)

Comment: By using the solution u gave the sprite looks like it is moving a little bit by its position. and i don't want this. i just want to zoom in/zoom out staying at its position

Comment: did u try changing the scale ratio in ScaleBy::create() method, Try ScaleBy::create(0.5f,0.5f); and Also after that do something like this, playButton->setAnchorPoint(0.5f,0.5f); it shouldn't move. The Movement was due to .7f(y scale ratio), as i said above you just need to short out your anchorpoint according to your scale ratio.